# What does 2/2 mean in output of kubectl get all -n cass-operator

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, cass-operator

I have a 3 node Kubernetes cluster and I have set up Cassandra on it using Cass-Operator. I am following the instructions from here - https://github.com/datastax/cass-operator

What does the 2/2 mean in the output of the following command

```
kubectl get all -n cass-operator
NAME                                READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/cass-operator-78c6469c6-6qhsb   1/1     Running   0          139m
pod/cluster1-dc1-default-sts-0      2/2     Running   0          138m
pod/cluster1-dc1-default-sts-1      2/2     Running   0          138m
pod/cluster1-dc1-default-sts-2      2/2     Running   0          138m
```

Does it mean that there are 3 data centres each running 2 cassandra nodes? It should be because my K8S cluster has only 3 nodes.

```
manuchadha25@cloudshell:~ (copper-frame-262317)$ gcloud compute instances list
NAME                                              ZONE            MACHINE_TYPE   PREEMPTIBLE  INTERNAL_IP  EXTERNAL_IP    STATUS
gke-cassandra-cluster-default-pool-92d544da-6fq8  europe-west4-a  n1-standard-1               10.164.0.26  34.91.214.233  RUNNING
gke-cassandra-cluster-default-pool-92d544da-g0b5  europe-west4-a  n1-standard-1               10.164.0.25  34.91.101.218  RUNNING
gke-cassandra-cluster-default-pool-92d544da-l87v  europe-west4-a  n1-standard-1               10.164.0.27  34.91.86.10    RUNNING
```

Or is Cassandra-operator running two containers per K8S Node?

Comment: In short it means that this pod is running 2 containers inside. Give me a few minutes and I will write you more precise answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you are deploying some application, one pod can have more than 1 container inside. If you will check [Kubernetes Pod docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-overview/#understanding-pods) you can find 2 typs:

**Pods that run a single container.**

> The "one-container-per-Pod" model is the most common Kubernetes use case; in this case, you can think of a Pod as a wrapper around a single container, and Kubernetes manages the Pods rather than the containers directly.

**Pods that run multiple containers that need to work together.**

> A Pod might encapsulate an application composed of multiple co-located containers that are tightly coupled and need to share resources. These co-located containers might form a single cohesive unit of service--one container serving files from a shared volume to the public, while a separate "sidecar" container refreshes or updates those files. The Pod wraps these containers and storage resources together as a single manageable entity.

More information you can find in [this docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-overview).

How `Pod` configuration YAML with 2 containers looks like can be found [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/communicate-containers-same-pod-shared-volume/#creating-a-pod-that-runs-two-containers). In `.spec.containers` you can specify 2 or more containers.

Ive deployed those YAMLs.

```
$ kubectl get po -n cass-operator
NAME                             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
cass-operator-78c9999797-gb88g   1/1     Running   0          4m26s
cluster1-dc1-default-sts-0       2/2     Running   0          4m12s
cluster1-dc1-default-sts-1       2/2     Running   0          4m12s
cluster1-dc1-default-sts-2       2/2     Running   0          4m12s
```

Now you have to describe pod. In my example its:

```
$ kubectl describe po cluster1-dc1-default-sts-0 -n cass-operator
```

And under `Containers:` you can find details like image, ports, state, mounts, etc.

```
Containers:
  cassandra:
    Container ID:   docker://49b58eacc380da6c29928677e84082373d4330a91c29b29f3f3b021e43c21a38
    Image:          datastax/cassandra-mgmtapi-3_11_6:v0.1.5
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://datastax/cassandra-mgmtapi-3_11_6@sha256:aa7d6072607e60b1dfddd5877dcdf436660bacd31dd4aa6c8c2b85978c9fd170
   ....
  server-system-logger:
    Container ID:  docker://d0b572e767236e2baab7b67d5ad0fc6656b862fc4e463aa1836de80d34f608ea
    Image:         busybox
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://busybox@sha256:2131f09e4044327fd101ca1fd4043e6f3ad921ae7ee901e9142e6e36b354a907
    Port:          <none>
```

So this pod runs 2 containers

- name: `cassandra`
- name: `server-system-logger`

**What when there is pod with `1/2`?**

It means that in this specific `pod` only 1 container is `running`. Containers states are `Waiting`, `Running` and `Terminated`. More information you can find [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#container-states).

Use case?
You can check logs from specified container.

```
$ kubectl logs cluster1-dc1-default-sts-0 -n cass-operator -c cassandra
Starting Management API
/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 74: [: missing `]'
Running java -Xms128m -Xmx128m -jar /opt/mgmtapi/datastax-mgmtapi-server-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar --cassandra-socket /tmp/cassandra.sock --host tcp://0.0.0.0:8080 --host file:///tmp/oss-mgmt.sock --explicit-start true --cassandra-home /var/lib/cassandra/
INFO  [main] 2020-07-03 13:43:08,199 Cli.java:343 - Cassandra Version 3.11.6
INFO  [main] 2020-07-03 13:43:08,709 ResteasyDeploymentImpl.java:551 - RESTEASY002225: Deploying javax.ws.rs.core.Application: class com.datastax.mgmtapi.ManagementApplication
...
```

Or

```
$ kubectl logs cluster1-dc1-default-sts-0 -n cass-operator -c server-system-logger
INFO  [main] 2020-07-03 13:44:04,588 YamlConfigurationLoader.java:89 - Configuration location: file:/etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml
INFO  [main] 2020-07-03 13:44:06,137 Config.java:516 - Node configuration:[allocate_tokens_for_keyspace=null; authenticator=org.apache.cassandra.auth.PasswordAuthenticator; authorizer=org.apache.cassandra.auth.CassandraAuthorizer; auto_bootstrap=true; auto_snapshot=true;
...
```

You can also get this pod YAML to verify. You can do it in this example by:

```
$ kubectl get po cluster1-dc1-default-sts-0 -n cass-operator -o yaml
```

**As addition to your question:**

**Or is Cassandra-operator running two containers per K8S Node?**

It's running two containers per pod. You can check which pod was scheduled to which node by:

```
$ kubectl get pods -n cass-operator -o wide
NAME                             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP          NODE                                       NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
cass-operator-78c9999797-gb88g   1/1     Running   0          20m   10.44.1.4   gke-cluster-2-default-pool-5aa60336-n3hr   <none>           <none>
cluster1-dc1-default-sts-0       2/2     Running   0          19m   10.44.1.5   gke-cluster-2-default-pool-5aa60336-n3hr   <none>           <none>
cluster1-dc1-default-sts-1       2/2     Running   0          19m   10.44.2.3   gke-cluster-2-default-pool-5aa60336-dl2g   <none>           <none>
cluster1-dc1-default-sts-2       2/2     Running   0          19m   10.44.0.9   gke-cluster-2-default-pool-5aa60336-m7ms   <none>           <none>
```

Comment: Thanks mate. Very well explained. I like to stay in contact with developers outside SO. Please feel free to check my profile and connect with me on LinkedIn if you would like to.

Comment: beautifully explained!